# R - grep function not matching properly

Tags: r

to simplify, suppose:

```
tst <- c("DG-c", "DG-cl")
```

when i use length(grep()) for "DG-c" and "DG-cl" i should get 1 both times right?

```
length(grep("DG-c", tst))
[1] 2
length(grep("DG-cl", tst))
[1] 1
```

Why does it seem to assume if all characters in the pattern match x then it is a match? How can I change this?

Thanks

Comment: Because you are matching regular expressions. Have a look at e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: No, it is correct to get 2, as `"DG-cl"`  contains `"DG-c"` as well. If you want exact match use `==` or `%in%` operators or `match` function

Comment: ah thanks, so:
length("DG-c" %in% tst)

Answer (score 1):

To get the result you were expecting using `grep`, consider using `^` `$` anchors for exact matching.

`^` for matching the beginning of the string.

`$` for matching the end of the string.

```r
tst <- c("DG-c", "DG-cl")

length(grep("^DG-c$", tst))
#> [1] 1

length(grep("^DG-cl$", tst))
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

```
grep("DG-c", tst)
[1] 1 2
length(grep("DG-c", tst))
[1] 2

length(grep("DG-c$", tst))
[1] 1
```

Comment: That will return wrong result for `tst <- c("DG-c", "rDG-c")`. Probably `length(grep("^DG-c$", tst))` is better

Comment: It's true, but my answer was based on OP's sample.